# Point data extraction and printing as a TABLE

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine, modis, table, ndvi

I am working with MODIS-NDVI image collection in Google Earth Engine. Below, you can find a script which is creating a chart of NDVI values over the given period for particular location. I would like to print it as a table or text in Console/Panel, but could not find code for it. Is there anyway to do it?

```
var point = ee.Geometry.Point([10.455856189782935, 50.440969544991205]);

var image = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD13A1').
      filterDate('2018-01-01','2018-12-31')
        .select('NDVI');

var div_ndvi = function(image) {
  var NDVI_0 = image.select("NDVI");
  var NDVI_1 = NDVI_0.divide(10000);
  return image.addBands(NDVI_1);
};

var withN = image.map(div_ndvi);

print(withN);

var chart = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion(withN, point, ee.Reducer.first(), 'NDVI_1', 500);

print(chart)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want the information in a list. You can do that using reduceRegion (to get the actual NDVI value at your geometry), add that as a property to each image and then extract those properties of all images in your collection using aggregate_array

```
// Make a 'table' in the console
var addNDVIatPoint = withN.map(function(image){
  return image.set(image.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.first(), point))
})
// extract as 'table'
var table = ee.List(addNDVIatPoint.aggregate_array('NDVI_1'))
var datesMillis = ee.List(addNDVIatPoint.aggregate_array('system:time_start'))

print(table); print(datesMillis)
```

[link script](https://code.earthengine.google.com/10820878abad81a916485722009dc42d), where I also added how you could download a CSV table of the list you printed in the console

Comment: Thanks for solution. It works well. Can you please also assist me on finding command for printing out  this list in panel. I have created panel and tried to add the list by writing "panel.add(table)". But, it did not work and I received a message "Only a ui.Widget can be added to a panel.".

Comment: Try something like this, or use evaluate() when implementing this on larger scripts to make sure your browser does not stop responding: Map.add(ui.Label(table.getInfo()))

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. It worked well. But, it prints the data in horizontal axis when it is added to the panel. How can I make it vertically and with dates?

Comment: How can I make it vertically and with dates?